# syslog messages not displayed - dropwizard

Tags: macos, dropwizard, syslog

I created a dropwizard application that uses syslog to logging. I am using Mac OS version 10.10.3. My appenders in Configuration.yml file are as follows.

```
logging:   
  level: INFO   
    appenders:
    - type: file
      currentLogFilename: /var/log/myapp.log
      threshold: INFO
      archive: true
      archivedLogFilenamePattern: /var/log/myapp-%d.log
      archivedFileCount: 5
    - type: syslog
      host: localhost
      port: 514
      threshold: INFO
```

The file myapp.log is populated correctly. But when I do

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/system.log
```

I am not able to see the messages. I followed answer from [How to start Syslogd server on Mac to accept remote logging messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510563/how-to-start-syslogd-server-on-mac-to-accept-remote-logging-messages) but still I was not able to see the messages. However if I do

```
sudo tcpdump -i lo0 host 127.0.0.1 and udp port 514
```

I am able see the packets. My syslog.conf looks like this

```
install.*                       @127.0.0.1:32376
```

What am I missing here?